# JavaFX component that emulates JTable

Tags: java, swing, frameworks, jtable, javafx

I have a large dataset that needs to be displayed for users and looking for Swing's `JTable` like component in `JavaFX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you read Amy Fowler's recent blog post (especially point 6):

*Any Swing component can be embedded in a JavaFX scene graph using the SwingComponent wrap() function. This conveniently allows you to directly leverage those Swing components which you've already configured, customized, and hooked to your application data; all that Java code can remain happily unmodified. Once you've created the structure of your scene's layout, you can pull your Swing components into the appropriate locations.*

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aim/archive/2009/06/insiders_guide.html

Comment: Link is broken  :(

Answer (score 2):

Use a `TableView` control.

- [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html)
- [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm)

A TableView is a "virtualized" control which efficiently reuses a small number of node cells to present a view into potentially very large data sets.

[image: table view sample]

Note, other answers on this page which were written before 2012 concern JavaFX 1.x and are obsolete.

Comment: If you have already implemented using JTable (Swing), embed it in your JavaFX Application. If not use JavaFX Tableview. If your dataset has a large no of columns (about more than 100), don't use JavaFX Tableview as it gives poor performance. Use JTable instead. (The number of rows won't affect performance because the rows are lazily loaded.)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap JTable to be used in JavaFX. Check out the following article
http://java.dzone.com/articles/javafx-reintroduce-swing-jtabl

Comment: The article looks interesting but the code will not work under JavaFX 1.2.

Comment: You may also find more info at http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aim/archive/2009/06/insiders_guide.html